# How to call a method that takes an array of integer numbers and get the return statement

Tags: java, arrays, parameters

I want to use the method averageCalc() which takes an array of integer numbers as its parameter and returns the average which is of double type. How can I call my method I want to return the array as a average of type double .

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int number = 0;
   number = average.int [] num (  4, 3, 9);  
   System.out.println(number);

}
```

This is my method called averageCalc() that takes an array of integer numbers and returns the average of the numbers in the array

```
public double averageCalc(int[] num) {  
int result =0;
double average = 0;

for (int i=0; i < num.length; i++) {

result = result + num[i]; 

}
average = (double)result / num.length;; 
return average;

}
```

Comment: Asking, how to name methods is a minefield. One whould argue the name should follow grammar: `calcAverage()`. One would say function first: `averageCalc()`. One would say methods always calculate/do something: `average()`. Try to understand the dominant variant of the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form an array:

```
int[] numbers = {4, 3, 9};
```

then pass it to the method:

```
double average = averageCalc(numbers);
```

---

Better, declare your method as having a varargs parameter:

```
public double averageCalc(int... num) { 
    // same method body - num is actually int[]
}
```

Then you can call it more conveniently like this:

```
double average = averageCalc(4, 3, 9);
```

Comment: Ok I can call my method now.

So if I want to give my method an integer array I write 
     public double averageCalc(int... num)
I didn't knew about the int...num part

Thank you it works now :))

Answer (score 1):

You should maybe consider using a stream for such a simple operation, like so:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double average = IntStream.of(4, 3, 9).average().getAsDouble();
    System.out.println(average);
}
```